# Is it possible in javascript to pluck array based on it's contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form data that captured video, photo, audio and text data. The number of these fields are dynamic so I could have multiple video, audio fields etc and this is causing the form to crash or become too slow when submitting. I am currently doing the submit via a normal form action submit without ajax.

I want to revise the behaviour so I could submit the form fields one request a time and I could display progress to the client side something like this.

```
Basic information has been saved.
Audio 1 uploaded.
Video 2 uploaded.
Video 3 currently uploading ...
Video 4 pending.
Audio 5 pending.
```

Here's how the form data looks when I run the `form.serializeArray()`

```
0: {name: "utf8", value: "✓"}
1: {name: "authenticity_token", value: "token data here"}
2: {name: "data[name]", value: "a"}
3: {name: "response[100]", value: "data:video/webm;base64,...."}
4: {name: "response[101]", value: "text data here"}
5: {name: "privacy_policy", value: "1"}
```

Now I want to chop this array for a separate Ajax form request like the ff:

Request 1 - Basic information

```
0: {name: "utf8", value: "✓"}
1: {name: "authenticity_token", value: "token data here"}
2: {name: "data[name]", value: "a"}
```

Request 2 - Video data

```
0: {name: "utf8", value: "✓"}
1: {name: "authenticity_token", value: "token data here"}
2: {name: "response[100]", value: "data:video/webm;base64,...."}
```

Request 3 - Text data

```
0: {name: "utf8", value: "✓"}
1: {name: "authenticity_token", value: "token data here"}
2: {name: "response[101]", value: "text data here"}
```

Now I want to know if there's a built-in way in javascript to achieve this way of chopping an array. Something like
`basic_info = formdata.remove(name, 'response')`.

Or is there none? And I need to do it manually by looping through this array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the objects you want to be present in each array first, then `.map` the rest to create a new array, with each new array item being a subarray containing those objects plus the item being iterated over:

```js
const input = [
  {name: "utf8", value: "✓"},
  {name: "authenticity_token", value: "token data here"},
  {name: "data[name]", value: "a"},
  {name: "response[100]", value: "data:video/webm;base64,...."},
  {name: "response[101]", value: "text data here"},
  {name: "privacy_policy", value: "1"}
];
const [item1, item2, ...rest] = input;
const output = rest.map(item3 => [item1, item2, item3]);
console.log(output);
```

If you don't want the `privacy_policy`, just `pop()` it from the `input` first.